# Controllers folder missing Umbraco 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco8

I installed Umbraco 8.4 as per the instructions found at https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/install-umbraco-with-nuget

Once done within Visual Studio 2017 i tried to created a new Controller and the folder (Controllers) was missing.

I'm not sure if i've missed something but i didnt want to create the folder manually in case it introduces new problems later down the line.

I thought to recreate the project but instead of selecting Empty as the project to use MVC but after reading through a few threads it seems the correct way is to select an empty project.

Under the bin directory i do see System.Web.Mvc.dll

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely **not** use the MVC project template when creating a new project - that will add all sorts of dependencies that will likely conflict with what comes with the Umbraco NuGet package.

Go with the "Empty" template and then add in the NuGet and it will give you the dependencies you need for Umbraco to run. If you need to add in other stuff from MVC afterwards, you can add these in a version that aligns with what the Umbraco package has added.

In regards to the Controllers folder - it really doesn't matter where this folder lives or what it is called. Controllers are registered by other means. You are totally fine to create this folder manually and call it whatever you prefer.

I think most people actually prefer to keep `Controllers` in a completely separate project in the VS solution. Then reference that project by your main project to ensure the compiled DLL is included in your web project - and thereby your controllers can be used by the Umbraco website itself. By doing this, you get a clean separation of your `.cs` source files so you won't accidentally be deploying those when you deploy your site. To do this you would of course require to add `UmbracoCms.Core` NuGet package to your other project in order to use Umbraco functionality.

Keep in mind if you are adding plain MVC controllers (not inheriting from the Umbraco base controllers - and therefore not getting automatically registered) you will need to manually register these controllers in the route table in order to access them.
This is no different from what you would do in a normal ASP.NET MVC project, but since this isn't added by default in an Umbraco project - you need to do it yourself.

See this answer for instructions on how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56972929/336105

Comment: To see an example of the setup @Claus is describing, see the [Umbraco Cloud documentation for setting up a Visual Studio project](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Umbraco-Cloud/Set-Up/Working-With-Visual-Studio/).  They create a solution with two projects: one for the Umbraco Website and one for your custom code.  Note: Their two projects end up being nested Git repos, which is discouraged by Git, and is a pain to deal with in Visual Studio, which lacks support for nested repos (probably because Git discourages them).